# Get the new url after Post by CURL

Tags: php, redirect, curl

This is a example:

The origin URL is `http://www.vietbando.com/maps/#t=1&sk=258+lý+Thường+Kiệt`

When I the form is posted.

It change to new URL like this

```
http://www.vietbando.com/maps/#t=1&sk=258+lý+Thường+Kiệt&l=4&kv=15.0132985,106.744091
```

How to get the new url ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to a redirect, the new URL should always be in the `Location` header in the response.

To get the headers included in your curl request, set the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option via `curl_set_opt`.

If you're more interested in just navigating to/GETing the next URL as opposed to grabbing the actual URL, you can just use `FOLLOW_REDIRECTS` setting.

Lastly, if you're doing any sort of HTTP work beyond a couple of calls, I would highly recommend using an HTTP library (because PHP cURL is torture).  See [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/), [Httpful](http://phphttpclient.com), or [Requests](http://requests.ryanmccue.info/).

Comment: I tried CURLOPT_HEADER and FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, but it dosen't work.  
Can you try this link <http://www.vietbando.com/maps/#t=1&sk=258+lý+Thường+Kiệt>  
It will change to <http://www.vietbando.com/maps/#t=1&sk=258+lý+Thường+Kiệt&l=6&kv=15.0132985,106.744091>

Answer (score 1):

In that case you'll can parse the header of your response to grab url.
You have to use this code to do this:

```
$ch_url = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch_url, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/)'; //your first url
curl_setopt($ch_url, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'AppleWebKit/530.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/2.0.172.39 Safari/530.5');
curl_setopt($ch_url, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch_url, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch_url, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); //we don't need to recieve the body of response
$headers = curl_exec($ch_url);
curl_close ($ch_url);

$pattern = '`.*?((http)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i'; //this regexp finds your url
if (preg_match_all($pattern,$headers,$matches))
    $url = $matches[1][0]; //your second url
```

Comment: I'm not understand well. This is code I do, but I do, but it not return the new url

$ch_url = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch_url, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.vietbando.com/maps/#t=1&sk=258+lý+Thường+Kiệt'); //your first url

curl_setopt($ch_url, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'AppleWebKit/530.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/2.0.172.39 Safari/530.5');

curl_setopt($ch_url, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch_url, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch_url, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); //we don't need to recieve the body of response

$headers = curl_exec($ch_url);

curl_close ($ch_url);

Comment: $pattern = '`.*?((http)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i'; //this regexp finds your url
if (preg_match_all($pattern,$headers,$matches)){
    $url = $matches[1][0]; //your second url
    echo $url;
}

Comment: So, this code will works if you make a request via cURL to the one page and it's redirect you to another one (302 or 301 redirect). Your link (http://www.vietbando.com/maps/#t=1&sk=258+lý+Thường+Kiệt) doesn't redirect to any page. That's why you can't get the new link, it's just not exist.
Please explain more clear how the second link is appeared. I don't understand this: 'When I the form is posted.'

Comment: sorry for my words.  THis site http://www.vietbando.com/maps/ has an input tag, but it doesn't have name attribute so I pass the value  from the url like this   http://www.vietbando.com/maps/#t=1&sk=268+Ly+Thuong+Kiet  . When you run the url, it will change to http://www.vietbando.com/maps/#t=1&sk=268+Ly+Thuong+Kiet&l=17&kv=10.7698825,106.658482  . I can do it by myself but I has huge url to do. I think CURL may do that but I don't find out the solution yet.

Comment: This link (http://www.vietbando.com/maps/#t=1&sk=268+Ly+Thuong+Kiet) doesn't rediderect me to the new one. So there is no redirect here. Try to change your code, then my code will works.
I've tried to get redirect in Chrome, Opera and Firefox on Mac but can't.

Comment: Change my code? This link [http://www.vietbando.com/maps/#t=1&sk=268+Ly+Thuong+Kiet](http://www.vietbando.com/maps/#t=1&sk=268+Ly+Thuong+Kiet) is likely Google Maps, it is not my own. When you click the link, it will change [http://www.freeimagehosting.net/79hhf](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/79hhf). I have a lot of addresses, and I want to look for their coordinate.  If it doesn't redirect, is there any way to do?

Comment: I got it now. This redirect is generated by javascript so ypu can't recieve the new url using any server-side script. The best way to resolve this problem is useng the API of this service.